# Is there a tool to improve asp .net web forms automatically change control size

Tags: .net

I have some web form in asp .net .controls of webform had not size and arranged very well .Is a tool to convert HTML table to CSS in design mode.most of control placed not very well because I use table.

I mean something like HTML table to CSS converter in design mode.most of control placed not very well because I use table.